# Find joint CDF given a joint PDF

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, marginal-distribution

> Let $X$ and $Y$ have a joint density function given by
>   $$
> f(x, y) =
> \begin{cases}
> 1, & \text{for } 0\leq x\leq2,\;\max(0,\,x-1)\leq y\leq \min(1,\,x), \\
> 0, & \text{otherwise}.
> \end{cases}
> $$
>   Determine the joint and marginal distribution functions.

---

I know that $F_{XY}(x, y) = \int_{-\infty}^x\int_{-\infty}^y f(u, v)\;dudv$. But I have no idea how to apply this fact.

The obvious case that I can find is that if  $x > 2$, then $F_{XY}(x, y) = 1$.

Some other bounds are e.g. $0<x<1$ and $0<y<x$, but how do I find the CDF for this case? I can find some of the bounds, but don't know how to use them for the integrals.

Comment: For these integrals, the lower limit is 0 not $-\infty$.

Comment: Yeah, I've kind of understood that part. But how do I set up the rest of the integral? Just like this $\int_0^x \int_0^y f(x, y)\;dudv = \int_0^x \int_0^y 1\;dudv$?
Though, with the bounds I've given above, I end up with wrong solution for some reason.

Comment: For $0\leq x\leq 1$, we get $0\leq y\leq x$, but not sure how to find the bounds when $1\leq x \leq 2$. My guess was to plug in $x$ into $max(0, x-1) \leq y \leq min(1, x)$, but end up with the wrong results. E.g. $max(0, 2 - 1) \leq y \leq min(1, 2) = 1 \leq y \leq 1$ which doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Revised correction, based on conversation with Maxim!

Summary for all $(x,y)$. For $x\le 0$ or $y\le 0,\ F(x,y)=0$.

For $0\lt x\le 1,\ 0\le y\le 1$, two parts:

1) $0\lt y\le x,\ F(x,y)=xy-\frac{y^2}{2}$,

2) $x\lt y\le 1,\ F(x,y)=\frac{x^2}{2}$,

For $1\lt x,\ 0\le y\le 1$, two parts: [part 2) vacuous for $x\gt 2$]

1) $0\le y\le x-1,\ F(x,y)=y$,

2) $x-1\lt y\le1,\ F(x,y)=xy-\frac{y^2}{2}-\frac{(x-1)^2}{2}$,

For $1\lt y,\ F(x,y)=F(x,1)$.

Comment: I seem to get different results for the first integral. I get $\int_0^x\int_x^y\,dudv = \int_0^x (y - x)\;dv = (yv - xv)|_0^x = xy - x^2$. Should the integral be in $dxdy$ instead, as that do give me the right solution. But in all the definitions of the CDF, it's stated as other variables like $dudv$. I think I'm potentially misunderstanding something?

Comment: @wednesdaymike Your integrand $(y-x)$ should be $(y-v)$.  As a check put in the upper limit, the value should be $\frac{1}{2}$.  Your expression gives 0.

Comment: To see it more clearly, diagram $f(x,y)=1$.  It consists of two triangles.  The first has $(x,y)=(0,0),(0,1),(1,1)$ as vertices.  The second has $(x,y)=(1,0),(1,1),(2,1)$ as vertices.

Comment: To get cdf from the diagram, set $(x,y)$ at a point inside a triangle and draw straight lines from that point to the axes, making a rectangle with the axes.  The area inside the rectangle within the triangle(s) is the cdf at that point.

Comment: If $f$ is $f_{X,Y}$, then your first integral gives $P(X < y, Y < x)$. The second integral is incorrect (you probably shouldn't use the same name for a free and a bound variable). Also, this can't be the complete answer because a cdf has to be between $0$ and $1$. The full result is
$$\int_{-\infty}^x \int_{-\infty}^y f(t_1, t_2) dt_2 dt_1 = \\
\cases{
0 & $x < 0 \lor y < 0$ \\
1 & $2 < x \land 1 < y$ \\
x \min(x, y) - \frac 1 2 \min(x, y)^2 & $0 \leq x \leq 1$ \\
-\frac 1 2 (\min(x, 1 + y) - \min(1, y))^2 + \min(x, 1 + y) - \frac 1 2 &
 $1 < x \land \lnot (2 < x \land 1 < y)$}.$$

Comment: Your piecewise answer is still incorrect. Consider that with the standard notation for an iterated integral, $\int_0^2 \int_0^1 f(x, y) dx dy = 1/2$, not $1$.

Comment: @Maxim  What are you referring to?

Comment: You have two different answers now, the first one gives $y^2/2 + (x - 1) y - (x - 1)^2/2$ for $1 < x < 2$, the second one only for $1 < x \leq y + 1$. I'm saying that both of those are incorrect. To begin sorting it out, first note that in your integrals you're using $y$ as the upper limit for the *first* argument of $f$.

Comment: The summary is for all $(x,y)$ is correct.  For the preliminary section, I calculated the results only for $x$ in the (final) indicated ranges.  The summary was to correct it for x outside.  I agree the integrals could have been expressed better with dummy variables.  For $0\lt x\lt y,\ \int_0^x\int_v^ydudv$ and for $1\lt x \lt 1+y,\ \int_1^x\int_{v-1}^ydudv$.  If you look at my earlier comment you will see that calculus is unnecessary.  Plane geometry will suffice.

Comment: Let us clarify one thing first: you're computing $\int_{-\infty}^x \int_{-\infty}^y f(t_2, t_1) dt_2 dt_1$, not $\int_{-\infty}^x \int_{-\infty}^y f(t_1, t_2) dt_2 dt_1$, is that correct?

Comment: $u$ is dummy variable in the $y$ direction, $v$ is dummy variable in the $x$ direction.  The  entir integrand is zero except for two triangular patches where it is one.   If you want to reverse the order you would have to further subdivide the domains of integration. The domain of integral for $F(x,y)$ is over  the intersection of the non-zero integrand with a rectangle having an upper right corner at $(x,y)$.

Comment: But you haven't answered the question. $f(t_2, t_1)$ is not the same as $f(t_1, t_2)$. You say your integration variables are $u$ and $v$, but you don't say whether the integrand is $f(u, v)$ or $f(v, u)$. Or, if you prefer to put it that way, if the upper right corner of a large rectangle is at $(x, y)$, does the parallelogram where $f$ is non-zero has two edges parallel to the axis along which you take the $x$ coordinate or two edges parallel to the axis along which you take the $y$ coordinate?

Comment: The rectangle vertices are $(0,0),\ (x,0).\ (x,y),\ (0,y)$.  I don't understand your point about $f(u,v)$ or $f(v,u)$.  The area where $f(x,y)=1$ is defined by two triangles described previously,  Vertices are $(0,0),\ (0,1),\ (1,1)$ and $(1,0),\ (1,1),\ (2,1)$.  For both triangles intersected with rectangle, $y$ integration is done first  The integrand is constant in the domain, in which case $F(x,y)$ can be obtained by elementary geometry, each piece is the difference between the area of a rectangle and the area of a triangle.

Comment: I see what the problem is. Those two triangles are not the domain where $f = 1$. $f(1/2, 1/4) = 1, f(1/4, 1/2) = 0$. The second vertex of the first triangle should be $(1, 0)$.

Comment: Finally I understand.  I had the domain wrong.  I corrected my result (see answer) for the parallelogram.  The calculation was done with plane geometry.   Using integrals would take longer to write down.

Comment: The case $x > 2$ is missing though.

Comment: @Maxim I forgot - has been added.

Answer (score 1):

Let 
$$f_{X, Y}(x, y) = [0 \leq x \leq 2 \land \max(0, x-1) \leq y \leq \min(1, x)],$$ where $[P]$ is $1$ if $P$ is true and $0$ otherwise. Consider the cases $0 \leq x \leq 1$ and $1 < x \leq 2$ separately to get rid of $\min$ and $\max$ and verify that
$$f_{X, Y}(x, y) = [0 \leq y \leq 1 \land y \leq x \leq y + 1].$$
Integrating out the variable $x$ gives $1$ if the horizontal line intersects the parallelogram and $0$ otherwise:
$$f_Y(y) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f_{X, Y}(x, y) dx = [0 \leq y \leq 1],$$
from which the marginal cdf of $Y$ is
$$F_Y(y) = y \,[0 \leq y \leq 1] + [1 < y].$$

The marginal pdf of $X$ is symmetric wrt the line $x = 1$:
$$f_X(x) = x \,[0 \leq x \leq 1] + (2 - x) \,[1 < x \leq 2], \\
F_X(x) = \frac {x^2} 2 \,[0 \leq x \leq 1] +
 \left( 2 x - \frac {x^2} 2 - 1 \right) [1 < x \leq 2] +
 [2 < x].$$

To find $F_{X, Y}(x, y)$, first take $(x, y)$ inside the parallelogram:
$$G(x, y) =
\int_{-\infty}^x \int_{-\infty}^y f_{X, Y}(u, v) dv du = \\
\left( x y - \frac {y^2} 2 \right) \,[x \leq 1] +
 \left( x - \frac {(x - y)^2 + 1} 2 \right) [1 < x], \\
f_{X, Y}(x, y) = 1.$$
Note that this is different from $\int_{-\infty}^x \int_{-\infty}^y f_{X, Y}(u, v) du dv$.

For $(x, y)$ outside of the parallelogram, project the point onto the boundary:
$$F_{X, Y}(x, y) =
G(\min(x, y + 1, 2), \min(y, x, 1)) \,[0 \leq x \land 0 \leq y].$$

It can be verified that
$$F_X(x) = F_{X, Y}(x, \infty), \;F_Y(y) = F_{X, Y}(\infty, y).$$